# PHP if statement inside foreach to check WordPress pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I have a foreach statement that loops through all of the pages of a WordPress installation and lists them inside a div (using the get_pages() function).

It currently looks like this:

```
<?php 
  $pages = get_pages(); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $linkPage = '<a class="order" href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
    $linkPage .= $page->post_title;
    $linkPage .= '</a>';
    echo $linkPage;
  }
?>
```

What I need to do now is to add an if statement that inserts the string "*current*" after *class="order...* if the link is the one from the current page.

It may seem like a silly question, but I'm a front-end developer with little PHP experience, and every time I tried to add the if I got a syntax error, claiming there was an unexpected if statement.

I hope I made myself clear.
If any help can be provided, it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Add your full code with error if statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  //get id of your current page
  $post_id = $post[0]->ID;
  $pages = get_pages(); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $current = $post_id == $page->ID ? ' current' : '';
    $linkPage = '<a class="order '.$current.'" href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
    $linkPage .= $page->post_title;
    $linkPage .= '</a>';
    echo $linkPage;
  }
?>
```

Check this, I'm not sure if `$post_id = $post[0]->ID` works in your wp version, but the if-statement logic is correct and will work. Try to echo `$post_id` and `$current` if something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I had to do was change *$post_id = $post[0]->ID;* for *$post_id = $post->ID;*, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code :

```
<?php 
//get id of your current page
$post_id = get_the_ID();  
$pages = get_pages(); 
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
//Condition statement to add the class current
$current = $post_id == $page->ID ? 'current' : '';
$linkPage = '<a class="order '.$current.'" href="' . get_page_link(   $page->ID ) . '">';
$linkPage .= $page->post_title;
$linkPage .= '</a> <br> ';
echo $linkPage;
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you...